# Can you utilize adjectives after objects, nouns?

Tags: secondary-predicates

> I liked you hairy.

Can you construct a sentence that goes subject, verb, object, adjective? Can this be considered a complete sentence?

Comment: Why would it not be a complete sentence? Do you know what a complete sentence contains?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might say this to Bigfoot if he shaved off his fur, but you liked him better when he was hairy.

---

It's perfectly grammatical. In this construction, the verb *like* takes two complements:

1. An object (in this case, the pronoun *you*)
2. An object-oriented depictive secondary predicate (in this case, the adjective *hairy*).

That last bit is quite a mouthful, so I'll describe it a bit at a time:

1. We call it a **predicate** because it predicates on something semantically (the object, in this case).
2. We call it **secondary** because the sentence already has a primary predicate (*liked*).
3. We call it **depictive** because it describes something; the other kind is **resultative**.
4. We call it **object-oriented** because the thing it describes is the object; the other kind is **subject-oriented**, as we'll see below.

---

**Depictive** secondary predicates can describe subjects or objects:

> **He** came home **drunk**.   　(*drunk* describes the subject *he*)
>   I like **my coffee hot**. 　　 (*hot* describes the object *my coffee*)

**Resultative** secondary predicates tell us about the state the subject or object is in as a result of the action described in the primary predicate:

> **The lake** froze **solid**. 　　 (*solid* is the state of *the lake* resulting from freezing)
>   I painted **the wall red**.　　(*red* is the state of *the wall* as a result of painting)

So there are all sorts of secondary predicates out there.  This is just an overview of the basic types to give you a general idea; it's not a comprehensive description.  Note that some secondary predicates, unlike in your example, are adjuncts rather than complements.

---

If you'd like more information, you may be interested in the analysis presented in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*.  The specific construction with *like* in your example is described on pages 265-266.

Comment: I think I get that a verb may utilize arguments. In this, a verb like seems to contain two arguments, a subject and an object. A predicate announces something of an object (or subject)? The lake seems a noun phrase and this predicates on froze?